# How exact phrase search is performed by a Search Engine?

Tags: lucene, search-engine

I am using Lucene to search in a Data-set, I need to now how "" search (I mean exact phrase search) mechanism has been implemented?

I want to make it able to result all "little cat" hits when the user enters "littlecat". I now that I should manipulate the indexing code, but at least I should now how the "" search works.

Answer (score 0):

*I want to make it able to result all "little cat" hits when the user enters "littlecat"*

This might sound easy but it is very tough to implement. For a human being little and cat are two different words but for a computer it does not know little and cat seperately from **littlecat**, unless you have a dictionary and your code check those two words in dictionary. On the other hand searching for "**little cat**" can easily search for "**littlecat**" aswell. And i believe that this goes beyong the concept of an exact phrase search. Exact phrase search will only return littlecat if you search for "**littlecat**" and vice versa. Even google seemingly (expectedly too), doesnt return "little cat" on littlecat search

Answer (score 0):

A way to implement this is **Dynamic programming** - using a dictionary/corpus to compare your individual words against(and also the left over words after you have parsed the text into strings).

Think of it like you were writing a custom spell-checker or likewise. In this, there's also a scenario when more than one combination of words may be left over eg -**"walkingmydoginrain"** - here you could break the 1st word as "walk", or as "walking" , and this is the beauty of DP - since you know (from your corpus) that you can't form legitimate words from **"ingmydoginrain"** (ie rest of the string - you have just discovered that in this context - *you should pick the segmented word as "Walking" and NOT walk.*

Also think of it like not being able to find a match is adding to a **COST function** that you define, so you should get optimal results - meaning you can be sure that your text(un-separated with white spaces) will for sure be broken into legitimate words- *though there may be MORE than one possible word sequences in that line*(and hence, possibly also intent of the person seeking this)

You should be able to find pretty good base implementations over the web for your use case (read also : How does Google implement - "Did you mean" )

For now, see also -
[How to split text without spaces into list of words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words)