# Matching words within words Python

Tags: python, match, nltk

I am attempting to match words within a string however I do not want to match words that are part of another word... poor explanation, onto the example!

If have the word `pen`. I want to match that word within a string:

`01pennsylvania'` should not match as `pen` is part of the word `pennsylvania`.

However, `pensforsale` should match as `pen` isn't part of another word. I've been looking into NLTK but I can't find what I'm looking for, can anyone point me in the right direction? I know it would be impossible to do this for all word combinations but cutting down the noise marginally would be a great help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: You're talking about OS right? linux

Comment: So you need to both parse space-less text into words *and* then figure out which *mean* "pen" as opposed to just containing it? Would "pencil" count? How about if an animal is "penned" in?

Comment: I don't understand why `01pennsylvania` should not match `pen`, but `pensforsale` should...

Comment: You seem to be looking for matching word boundaries.  May I suggest you to look into a basic regex tutorial?

Comment: @DanielPilch your best bet is to find a spell check package and us its word dictionary.  Unfortunately, the one I prefer ([pyEnchant](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/)) isn't available for linux

Comment: You seem to think that Python has a large dictionary containing every word in the English language and the sentences in which it could be used. Sadly, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this [How to split text without spaces into list of words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words) as helpful start; by first trying to split your "pensforsale" into a list of words, you could then check for likely-variants, like plurals, etc.

This is going to be a very slow and error-prone way to go, though.