# Splitting words in a column

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

I have a csv with msg column and it has the following text

```
muchloveandhugs                                  
dudeseriously                                    
onemorepersonforthewin                           
havefreebiewoohoothankgod                        
thisismybestcategory                             
yupbabe                                          
didfreebee                                       
heykidforget                                     
hecomplainsaboutit
```

I know that nltk.corpus.words has a bunch of sensible words. My problem is how do I iterate it over the df[‘msg’] column so that I can get words such as

```
df[‘msg’]
much love and hugs
dude seriously
one more person for the win
```

Comment: The problem is broad and not well defined. For example, is `someone` one word or `some one`? You should share your existing code so there's somewhere to start with.

Comment: This is a complicated problem and prone to error since it relies heavily on probability. I found [this link](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb#(5)-Task:-Word-Segmentation) that suggests an approach. Personally, I'd be tempted to just ask Google; it will split up such strings and offer a "do you mean" link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words) about splitting words in strings with no spaces and not quite knowing what your data looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import wordninja

filename = 'mycsv.csv' # Put your filename here

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
for wordstring in df['msg']:
    split = wordninja.split(wordstring)
    # Do something with split
```