# tokenise string in a column of strings of .csv file

Tags: python, string, csv, tokenize

I have a .csv file where the column contains string values like "St_So update the DropMessage XML file_for save updateFillUp for save_command"

How would I do the tokenization in this case?

Comment: Hi, @Thyvapar, welcome to SO. To improve your chances of getting an answer i suggest that you take a look at [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you get the help you seek much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43531314/10828869 .

splits the sentence without space - https://github.com/keredson/wordninja