# Is there any way in python to seperate meaningful phrases or sentences from paragraph?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Using python I want my paragraph breaks into meaningful phrases for Example I have a paragraph format like this:

Input:

```
interpreted high-levelGeneral-purpose programming languageCreated by GUIDO VAN ROSSUMFirst released in 1991
```

Output:

```
interpreted high-level,
General-purpose programming language,
Created by GUIDO VAN ROSSUM,
First released in 1991,
```

Note: There is no space between two phrases in Input, So by using this input I want the output and mentioned above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split text without spaces into list of words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words)

Comment: You can use the above-mentioned link and try improving on top of it as its almost the similar use case you are looking for.

Comment: Instead of fixing the symptom (lack of separators), fix the cause. Given your question's tags, your text comes from scraping some HTML content. Fix your scraping code so that it keeps whitespaces where necessary (or inserts whitespaces in place of removed tags).