# Abbreviations and text without spaces how to split

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list

I have a list of Key, Value pairs

```
lst = [
  ('AAI', 'AirportAuthorityofIndia'),
  ('AAO', 'AssistantAccountsOfficer'),
  ('AB', 'AutonomousBodies'),
  ('ABA', 'AntiBoostMissile'),
  ('ABC', 'AuditBureauofCirculation'),
  ('ABM', 'AntiBallisticMissile'),
  ('ABVP', 'AkhilBharatiyaVidyarthiParishad'),
  ('AC', 'AssistantCollector'),
  ('AC', 'AirConditioner'),
  ('ACL', 'AccessControlList'),
  ('ACT', 'AssociationofComputerTechnology')]
```

What I am trying to do is add spaces between the words in the values. For example:

I need to split:

`('AAI', 'AirportAuthorityofIndia')` into `('AAI', 'Airport Authority of India')`

`('ACT', 'AssociationofComputerTechnology')` into `('ACT', 'Association of Computer Technology')`

If it's only capital letters I can do it using Regular Exression

```
[(abbr, re.sub(r'([a-z])(?=[A-Z])', r'\1 ', long)) for abbr, long in lst]
```

and I get

```
[('AAI', 'Airport Authorityof India')....etc
```

How do I add space between the lowercase letters as well?

Or is there any other method I can use to do this?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: The `of` here is problematic because otherwise you could split on capital letters. How do you expect to know if `of` is it's own word or part of a word like `roof`?

Comment: This is the problem I am Having as well. The word can be anything not just 'of'. It could also be something like 'in'. So i have no clue as to how to split all the attached words.

Answer (score 0):

I make a code like below. I hope this help you...

[A-Z]{1} - Occurence of capital letter only once followed by one or more lowercases [a-z]+

```
lst = [
('AAI', 'AirportAuthorityofIndia'),
('AAO', 'AssistantAccountsOfficer'),
('AB', 'AutonomousBodies'),
('ABA', 'AntiBoostMissile'),
('ABC', 'AuditBureauofCirculation'),
('ABM', 'AntiBallisticMissile'),
('ABVP', 'AkhilBharatiyaVidyarthiParishad'),
('AC', 'AssistantCollector'),
('AC', 'AirConditioner'),
('ACL', 'AccessControlList'),
('ACT', 'AssociationofComputerTechnology')]
for item in lst:
    result = re.findall(r'[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+', item[1]) 
    print(item[0],","," ".join(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A solution although far from ideal.

- Not using the abbreviations.
- Based on this [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11642687/1207193) using his `infer_spaces(s)` function

  - It uses ***a word dictionary file*** `words-by-frequency.txt`

In your case you have to include **native Indian words** like `Akhil`, `Bharatiya`, `Vidyarthi`, `Parishad` and expand it to **your custom word dictionary file** to make it fully generic. That's how I did bellow.

```py
    lst = [
      ('AAI', 'AirportAuthorityofIndia'),
      ('AAO', 'AssistantAccountsOfficer'),
       ...
    ]

    for (abbr, long) in lst:
        print(infer_spaces(long.lower()).title())
```

Outputs:

```py
Airport Authority Of India
Assistant Accounts Officer
Autonomous Bodies
Anti Boost Missile
Audit Bureau Of Circulation
Anti Ballistic Missile
Akhil Bharatiya Vidyarthi Parishad
Assistant Collector
Air Conditioner
Access Control List
Association Of Computer Technology
```