# Python split text without spaces but keep dates as they are

Tags: python, date, text, split

To split text without spaces, one can use wordninja, please see [How to split text without spaces into list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words). Here is the code to do the job.

```
sent = "Test12  to separate mergedwords butkeeprest asitis, say 1/2/2021 or 1.2.2021."

import wordninja
print(' '.join(wordninja.split(sent)))

output: Test 12 to separate merged words but keep rest as it is say 1 2 2021 or 1 2 2021
```

The wordninja looks great and works well for splitting those merged text. My question here is that how I can split text without spaces but keep the dates (and punctuations) as they are. An ideal output will be:

```
Test 12 to separate merged words but keep rest as it is, say 1/2/2021 or 1.2.2021
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can't really do this without some kind of lexicon/dictionary to know what an actual word is.

Comment: Why not do a basic split with [`sent.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) or [`re.split(r"[\W,/]+", sent)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) and take it from there? These are Python builtins.

Comment: Just spitballing but you could maybe find the locations of dates in the original string with regex, use wordninja on every part of the string that isn't a date, then combine the different segments?

Comment: @Jens I believe the idea here is that the words OP is trying to split could be arbitrarily combined so splitting them with builtins would be... painful

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to split our string into a list at every instance of a date then iterate over that list preserving items that matched the initial split pattern and calling `wordninja.split()` on everything else. Then recombine the list with join.

```
import re
def foo(s):
    return 'ninja'

string = 'Test12  to separate mergedwords butkeeprest asitis, say 1/2/2021 or 1.2.2021.'
pattern = re.compile(r'([0-9]{1,2}[/.][0-9]{1,2}[/.][0-9]{1,4})')

# Split the string up by things matching our pattern, preserve rest of string.
string_isolated_dates = re.split(pattern, string)

# Apply wordninja to everything that doesn't match our date pattern, join it all together. OP should replace foo in the next line with wordninja.split()
wordninja_applied = ' '.join([el if pattern.match(el) else foo(el) for el in string_isolated_dates])

print(wordninja_applied)
```

Output:

```
 ninja 1/2/2021 ninja 1.2.2021 ninja
```

Note: I replaced your function `wordninja.split()` with `foo()` just because I don't feel like downloading yet another nlp library. But my code demonstrates modifying the original string while preserving the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the following code, based on comments under my post (Thanks for comments):

```
import re
sent = "Test12  to separate mergedwords butkeeprest asitis, say 1/2/2021 or 1.2.2021."
sent = re.sub(","," ",sent)
corrected = ' '.join([' '.join(wordninja.split(w)) if w.isalnum() else w for w in sent.split(" ")])
print(corrected) 

output: Test 12  to separate merged words but keep rest as it is say 1/2/2021 or 1.2.2021.
```

It is not a straightforward solution, but works.

Comment: Oh that’s not quite what I meant by my comment, if I get a chance would it help you for me to write up an answer?

Comment: Thanks, 0x263A, Yes, it is good if you could please write your answer.