# How can I use pandas to read a text file and split the joined characters to different columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

An example of a Line in my text file:  **Hellothisismyquestion56464**

I want to my Data frame to look like this:

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hello | this | is | my | question | 56464 |

Comment: `pandas.read_fwf`

Comment: How will you decide where to divide those words?  Are they separated at all?

Comment: Here's an attempt to solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words/11642687#11642687

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of methods available to read a text file using pandas as mentioned [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-text-files-with-pandas/).

However, you need to specify a delimiter or a separator to achieve what you are trying to do. Following is an example code snippet of the same:

```
import pandas as pd
  
# read text file into pandas DataFrame and create header with names
df = pd.read_csv("gfg.txt", sep=" ", header=None, 
                 names=["Team1", "Team2"])
  
# display DataFrame
print(df)
```

Comment: Please include a code example in your answer. While links are useful, a good answer has enough text in it to "stand on its own".

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my answer accordingly