# Python how to select some string from sentence

Tags: python, string, split

I try to select some text in the list to create a new list but the text sticks together

```
market = ['cherry','apple','orange','mango','banana']
text = 'Iwanttobuyanapple mango orange andbanana'
new_text = text.split()
basket = []
for fruits in new_text:
    if fruits in market:
        basket.append(fruits)
print(basket)
```

The result is `['mango', 'orange']` but i want this `['apple, 'mango', 'orange', 'banana']`

Comment: See [How to split text without spaces into list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8870261/3832970).

Comment: Check for substrings instead of whole strings after splitting

Comment: Change the order: first loop through market and then check if that fruit is inisde the text (if you don't need the exact number of occurences of the fruit)

Answer (score 2):

You can search the other way round and look for the "market"items in the text.

```
market = ['cherry', 'apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'banana']
text = 'Iwanttobuyanapple mango orange andbanana'


def find_fruit(text, market):
    fruit = []
    for item in market:
        if item in text:
            fruit.append(item)
    return fruit

print(find_fruit(text, market))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `split()` won't work because the strings aren't delimited by space. Instead, check for substrings.

```
market = ['cherry', 'apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'banana']
text = 'Iwanttobuyanapple mango orange andbanana'
basket = []
for fruit in market:
    if fruit in text:
        basket.append(fruit)
print(basket)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not split the text.

```
market = ['cherry','apple','orange','mango','banana']
text = 'Iwanttobuyanapple mango orange andbanana'

basket = []
for fruits in market:
    if fruits in text:
        basket.append(fruits)
print(basket)
```

And also there is an alternating way to obtain the same result in just one line.

```
common = list(filter(lambda x:x in text, market))
print(common)
```