# How can I detect base noun in a word?

Tags: python, database, nlp

I have a project about database tables. I have to figure out which table is related to the others. For example; In my database, I have two tables. One of them's name is 'product' and another one's name is DimProduct. These are related to each other. I used an algorithm. It detects containment relationships.

Here comes my problem. I have a table name 'products' because of 's' the algorithm is not working. I need another way to find these tables' base nouns. What should I do? Are there any NLP library in python or any function to find noun?

[3 Different Table Names About Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmN4B.png)

Comment: Surely you'd want to do this by looking at the foreign keys of the database table, right? Is NLP really the easiest path here?

Comment: Actually, I thought about it but I want to find the relation between different databases' tables. As an example, I have a database called Market Which has a productDim table, and I have another database called BikeStore. It also has a product table. These tables' context are the same but they are not sharing a foreign key.

Comment: You could try LCS, longest common substring, which is a pretty simple algorithm for checking the similarity of two strings.

Comment: But how can I detect whether these common substrings are meaningful?

Comment: By length of substring relative to length of the two original strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try and answer the question, although strictly speaking, you should probably re-structure your database and relationships to a more suitable schema, incorporating the relationships within tables, rather than using the table name. For "base nouns", there are several things you can try:

- To split up the words, I'll refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8870261/2178980). However, given that you have an algorithm that is having trouble with "Product" vs "Products", I will assume you can already isolated "Product" from "DimProduct".
- To normalize, you can [Porter stem](https://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html) each word, and then find the common words between related tables:

```py
    from nltk.stem import *
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    stemmer.stem('Product')
    # 'product'
    stemmer.stem('Products')
    # 'product'
```

- If Porter stemming is too destructive, or presents duplication, then you can use the [`inflect` library](https://github.com/jaraco/inflect) to first check if each word is plural, and then singularize if it is:

```py
    import inflect
    p = inflect.engine()
    p.singular_noun('Product')
    # False
    p.singular_noun('Products')
    # 'Product'
```

- Another, more intensive way to find the "base form" of a word would be to use [spaCy's Lemmatizer](https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer):

```py
    import spacy
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    nlp('Product')[0].lemma_
    # 'product'
    nlp('Products')[0].lemma_
    # 'product'
```

Spacy is one of my favourite NLP tools, and you can use it to do a plethora of things, here are some [basic examples](https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-tokenization-stemming-and-lemmatization-with-spacy-library/) to start playing around with. If you are more interested in word similarity, then (for example) [Wordnet](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html#similarity), [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/), and [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#vectors-similarity) are good starting points, although there are many, many others out there. I hope this helps you a little bit!