# How to add "_" after splitting word in Python?

Tags: python

Example:
I am trying to split a list of column names called "startedat", "duecheck", "vehicleid" into "started" and "at", "due" and "check", "vehicle" and "id" respectively to get the desired output like started_at, due_check, vehicle_id.

I have tried using nltk word tokenize to split but it does not work. May I know what other methods I can do?

```
arr_list = ['startedat', 'duecheck', 'vehicleid']
for word in arr_list:
  print(word_tokenize(word))
```

Thank you.

Comment: "I have tried" - show that attempt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43531314/18286914 Hope wordninja will help you in this case

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest have added the attempt pls do mark up thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Install package**

```
pip install wordninja
```

**Code :**

```
import wordninja

col_list = ["startedat", "duecheck", "vehicleid"]

result = ["_".join(wordninja.split(x)) for x in col_list]
print(result)
```