# How can I effectively split text coming from a stream where the output is not necessarily new words but might be letters

Tags: python, string, text, stream

so I have a stream of text which comes in where the next item coming in is the all the previously generated text + some additional text which may either be a new word, letter, or part of a word. I'm trying to effectively split the text/arrange the text in a way which allows me to fully reconstruct the text as it's streaming. Here's an example:

`original text = "this is some prepended text which keeps showing up with the stream"`

and now let's say the stream comes in like this, notice the commented string, it contains a letter which is a continuation of a word in the following example and not a stand-alone letter:

```
def dummy_generator():
    yield 'I'm sorry to hear that you're feeling sad'
    time.sleep(0.2)
    yield '. Here are some suggestions that may help'
    time.sleep(0.2)
    yield 'uplift your mood:\n\n1. Take a walk outside'
    time.sleep(0.2)
    yield 'Fresh air and natural surroundings can do w' #For example, here there's a single letter which is continued in the next piece of text
    time.sleep(0.2)
    yield 'onders for your mood.\n\n2. Listen to music'
    time.sleep(0.2)
    yield  'Music has a powerful effect on our emotions'
    time.sleep(0.2)
    yield 'and can help lift our spirits.\n\n3. Practice'
    time.sleep(0.2)
    yield 'mindfulness: Taking a few minutes to focus on'
```

given this, is there a way to effectively split the text as it's being generated into the correct words?

Comment: The following book has some excellent examples of _"language processing"_, _[No Starch Press Publishing – Natural Language Processing with Python and spaCy](https://nostarch.com/NLPPython)_.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the input is ambiguous and you need a function that's a bit knowledgeable of the English language and can choose whether to merge the last word of a line with the first word of the next line, or not to merge. So for instance the function would compare `'w onders'` and `'wonders'` and decide that `'wonders'` is better English; likewise it would compare `'emotions and'` and `'emotionsand'` and decide that `'emotions and'` is better English.

In the case of `'outside Fresh'` and `'music Music'` it can use the capital letter to decide that the words should not be merged; but for `'w onders'` and `'emotions and'` it will need to refer to an English dictionary.

Related questions that can help you find an appropriate dictionary:

- [Latest Collins Scrabble Words list in text file?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/38366/latest-collins-scrabble-words-list-in-text-file)
- [How to split text without spaces into list of words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words)