# Processing malformed text data with machine learning or NLP

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, machine-learning

I'm trying to extract data from a few large textfiles containing entries about people. The problem is, though, I cannot control the way the data comes to me.

It is usually in a format like this:

> LASTNAME, Firstname Middlename (Maybe a Nickname)Why is this text hereJanuary, 25, 2012
>
> Firstname Lastname 2001 Some text that I don't care about
>
> Lastname, Firstname blah blah ... January 25, 2012 ...

Currently, I am using a *huge* regex that splits all `kindaCamelcase` words, all words that have a month name tacked onto the end, and a lot of special cases for names. Then I use more regex to extract a lot of combinations for the name and date.

This seems sub-optimal.

Are there any machine-learning libraries for Python that can parse malformed data that is somewhat structured?

I've tried NLTK, but it could not handle my dirty data. I'm tinkering with Orange right now and I like it's OOP style, but I'm not sure if I'm wasting my time.

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this to train a parser (with many input/output pairs):

```
training_data = (
  'LASTNAME, Firstname Middlename (Maybe a Nickname)FooBarJanuary 25, 2012',
   ['LASTNAME', 'Firstname', 'Middlename', 'Maybe a Nickname', 'January 25, 2012']
)
```

Is something like this possible or am I overestimating machine learning? Any suggestions will be appreciated, as I'd like to learn more about this topic.

Comment: You should provide us with more sample data that helps us understand the kind of strange things one would expect to see in your data.

Comment: Also are you sure you cannot contact the data provider(s) to figure out how they are generating this data in the first place? Maybe there are K different sources from their end, each of which uses a specific well defined style.

Comment: Sadly, those are the restrictions I have. The data I am getting has already been aggregated into a huge database and cannot be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up implementing a somewhat-complicated series of exhaustive regexes that encompassed every possible use case using text-based "filters" that were substituted with the appropriate regexes when the parser loaded.

If anyone's interested in the code, I'll edit it into this answer.

---

Here's basically what I used. To construct the regular expressions out of my "language", I had to make replacement classes:

```
class Replacer(object):
    def __call__(self, match):
        group = match.group(0)

        if group[1:].lower().endswith('_nm'):
            return '(?:' + Matcher(group).regex[1:]
        else:
            return '(?P<' + group[1:] + '>' + Matcher(group).regex[1:]
```

Then, I made a generic `Matcher` class, which constructed a regex for a particular pattern given the pattern name:

```
class Matcher(object):
    name_component =    r"([A-Z][A-Za-z|'|\-]+|[A-Z][a-z]{2,})"
    name_component_upper = r"([A-Z][A-Z|'|\-]+|[A-Z]{2,})"

    year = r'(1[89][0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2})'
    year_upper = year

    age = r'([1-9][0-9]|1[01][0-9])'
    age_upper = age

    ordinal = r'([1-9][0-9]|1[01][0-9])\s*(?:th|rd|nd|st|TH|RD|ND|ST)'
    ordinal_upper = ordinal

    date = r'((?:{0})\.? [0-9]{{1,2}}(?:th|rd|nd|st|TH|RD|ND|ST)?,? \d{{2,4}}|[0-9]{{1,2}} (?:{0}),? \d{{2,4}}|[0-9]{{1,2}}[\-/\.][0-9]{{1,2}}[\-/\.][0-9]{{2,4}})'.format('|'.join(months + months_short) + '|' + '|'.join(months + months_short).upper())
    date_upper = date

    matchers = [
        'name_component',
        'year',
        'age',
        'ordinal',
        'date',
    ]

    def __init__(self, match=''):
        capitalized = '_upper' if match.isupper() else ''
        match = match.lower()[1:]

        if match.endswith('_instant'):
            match = match[:-8]

        if match in self.matchers:
            self.regex = getattr(self, match + capitalized)
        elif len(match) == 1:
        elif 'year' in match:
            self.regex = getattr(self, 'year')
        else:
            self.regex = getattr(self, 'name_component' + capitalized)
```

Finally, there's the generic `Pattern` object:

```
class Pattern(object):
    def __init__(self, text='', escape=None):
        self.text = text
        self.matchers = []

        escape = not self.text.startswith('!') if escape is None else False

        if escape:
            self.regex = re.sub(r'([\[\].?+\-()\^\\])', r'\\\1', self.text)
        else:
            self.regex = self.text[1:]

        self.size = len(re.findall(r'(\$[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)', self.regex))

        self.regex = re.sub(r'(\$[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)', Replacer(), self.regex)
        self.regex = re.sub(r'\s+', r'\\s+', self.regex)

    def search(self, text):
        return re.search(self.regex, text)

    def findall(self, text, max_depth=1.0):
        results = []
        length = float(len(text))

        for result in re.finditer(self.regex, text):
            if result.start() / length < max_depth:
                results.extend(result.groups())

        return results

    def match(self, text):
        result = map(lambda x: (x.groupdict(), x.start()), re.finditer(self.regex, text))

        if result:
            return result
        else:
            return []
```

It got pretty complicated, but it worked. I'm not going to post all of the source code, but this should get someone started. In the end, it converted a file like this:

```
$LASTNAME, $FirstName $I. said on $date
```

Into a compiled regex with named capturing groups.

Comment: I'm interested in what kind of regexes you've used :-)

Comment: @IvoFlipse: Take a look at my answer. It's not too pretty, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the update, definitely worth an upvote now! I like how you wrapped all the regexes so you don't have to write the awful syntax every time

Comment: Second chunk of code is giving me indent error around "elif 'year' in match:"

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, mainly because of the problem with exporting data from Microsoft Office 2010 and the result is a join between two consecutive words at somewhat regular interval. The domain area is morhological operation like a spelling-checker. You can jump to machine learning solution or create a heuristics solution like I did.

The easy solution is to assume that the the newly-formed word is a combination of proper names (with first character capitalized).

The Second additional solution is to have a dictionary of valid words, and try a set of partition locations which generate two (or at least one) valid words. Another problem may arise when one of them is proper name which by definition is out of vocabulary in the previous dictionary. perhaps one way we can use word length statistic which can be used to identify whether a word is a mistakenly-formed word or actually a legitimate one.

In my case, this is part of manual correction of large corpora of text (a human-in-the-loop verification) but the only thing which can be automated is selection of probably-malformed words and its corrected recommendation.

Comment: this is a general solution which in my case doesn't require NLTK at all. I implement it in pure python.

Comment: I'm doing this with a huge chain of regexes. I was hoping for something more elegant, but I might stick with that...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the concatenated words, you can split them using a tokenizer:

> The [OpenNLP Tokenizers](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/opennlp/index.php?title=Tokenizer) segment an input character sequence into tokens. Tokens are usually words, punctuation, numbers, etc.

For example:

> Pierre Vinken, 61 years old, will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29.

is tokenized into:

> Pierre Vinken , 61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .

OpenNLP has a  "learnable tokenizer" that you can train. If the doesn't work, you can try the answers to: [Detect most likely words from text without spaces / combined words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2174093/907578) .

When splitting is done, you can eliminate the punctuation and pass it to a NER system such as [CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process):

> Johnson John Doe Maybe a Nickname Why is this text here January 25 2012

which outputs:

```
    Tokens
Id  Word    Lemma   Char begin  Char end    POS NER Normalized NER
1   Johnson Johnson 0   7   NNP PERSON  
2   John    John    8   12  NNP PERSON  
3   Doe Doe 13  16  NNP PERSON  
4   Maybe   maybe   17  22  RB  O   
5   a   a   23  24  DT  O   
6   Nickname    nickname    25  33  NN  MISC    
7   Why why 34  37  WRB MISC    
8   is  be  38  40  VBZ O   
9   this    this    41  45  DT  O   
10  text    text    46  50  NN  O   
11  here    here    51  55  RB  O   
12  January January 56  63  NNP DATE    2012-01-25
13  25  25  64  66  CD  DATE    2012-01-25
14  2012    2012    67  71  CD  DATE    2012-01-25
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried using NLTK's tokenizer, but the data just doesn't want to cooperate (sometimes NLTK detects names, but sometimes it doesn't). CoreNLP looks *really* accurate, but it isn't in Python, so I'll have a really hard time using it. But if my approach fails, I think CoreNLP is my next tactic.

Answer (score 0):

One part of your problem: "all words that have a month name tacked onto the end,"

If as appears to be the case you have a date in the format `Monthname 1-or-2-digit-day-number, yyyy` at the end of the string, you should use a regex to munch that off first. Then you have a now much simpler job on the remainder of the input string.

Note: Otherwise you could run into problems with given names which are also month names e.g. April, May, June, August. Also March is a surname which could be used as a "middle name" e.g. `SMITH, John March`.

Your use of the "last/first/middle" terminology is "interesting". There are potential problems if your data includes non-Anglo names like these:

`Mao Zedong` aka `Mao Ze Dong` aka `Mao Tse Tung`
`Sima Qian` aka `Ssu-ma Ch'ien`
`Saddam Hussein Abd al-Majid al-Tikriti`
`Noda Yoshihiko`
`Kossuth Lajos`
`José Luis Rodríguez Zapatero`
`Pedro Manuel Mamede Passos Coelho`
`Sukarno`

Comment: I've accounted for the names crudely with regex by matching consecutive capitalized (or camel-cased) words in the beginning of the string (with `-` and `'`) already, but I'm not sure if that's optimal.

Comment: As for the dates, I have about seven regexes for that: `Jan. 21, 2011`, `January 21, 2011`, `21 Jan. 2011`, `21 January 2011`, `2011`, etc. It's really brute-force.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers, to get you started:

- for date parsing, you could start with a couple of regexes, and then you could use [chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) or [jChronic](https://github.com/samtingleff/jchronic)
- for names, these [OpenNlp models](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/opennlp/index.php?title=Name_Finder) should work

As for training a machine learning model yourself, this is not so straightforward, especially regarding training data (work effort)...

Comment: Currently, I'm using a ton of regexes to match patterns in the names (as they always appear in the first sentence). Once I get the name, I use a Python name parser library to format it nicely. Then, I use like 10 regexes to match every possible date format and extract those as well. It's not an elegant solution, but it works. I was just wondering if machine learning could be of assistance to me. But thanks for the answer. I'll look into OpenNLP a bit more, as everybody is suggesting it over NLTK.